# script.aculo.us using appear and fade

Tags: fade, effects, scriptaculous

Misusing **script.aculo.us** to **fade and appear effects** on tabs, I lost de fading effect when the mouse goes too fast.
How to assure to get the fadding effect?
**([The full code is online](http://chabada.esy.es/tests/0002.html))**

```
<script>
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
        var Tabs = $$('#tabs img:not([src*=over])'); /* <img src= not containing "over" */
        for (var i=0; i<Tabs.length; i++) {
            var tab = Tabs[i];
            console.log(tab.id)
            $(tab.id+'_over').observe('mouseout', function(){
                this.fade({duration:.2,to:0}); /* !!! if mouse too fast, doesn't fade sometime */
            });
            Event.observe(tab, 'mouseover', function(){
                $(this.id+'_over').appear({duration:.2,to:1});
            });
        }
    })();
</script>


<body>

    <div id="tabs">

        <div class="tab">
        <a href="test.html?on=A">
        <img src="test/tab_A.gif"      id="A"/>
        <img src="test/tab_A_over.gif" id="A_over" style="display:none;"/>
        </a>
        </div>

        ... B, C

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `afterFinish` option calling `appear` effect and check if the mousse is over the element `if ($$('#'+obj.element.id+':hover').length==0)`.**([See at the same place](http://chabada.esy.es/tests/0002.html))**